# Are cache ways in gem5 explicit or are they implied/derived from the number of cache sets and cache size?

Tags: caching, simulator, gem5

I am trying to implement a gem5 version of HybCache as described in H*YBCACHE: Hybrid Side-Channel-Resilient Caches for Trusted Execution Environments* (which can be found at https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec20spring_dessouky_prepub.pdf).

A brief summary of HybCache is that a subset of all the cache is reserved for use by secure processes and are isolated. This is achieved by using a limited subset of cache ways when the process is in 'isolated' mode.  Non-isolated processes uses the cache operations normally, having access to the entire cache and using the replacement policy and associativity given in the configuration. The isolated subset of cache ways uses random replacement policy and is fully associative. Here is a picture demonstrating the idea.

[image: cache sets and cache ways with way 6 and 7 representing isolated ways]

The ways 6 and 7 are grey and represent the isolated cache ways.

So, I need to manipulate the placement of data into these ways. My question is, since I have found no mention of cache ways in the gem5 code, does that mean that the cache ways only exist logically? That is, do I have to manually calculate the location of each cache way? If cache ways are used in gem5, then were are they used? What is the file name?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is only valid for the [Classic cache model](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/memory_system/classic_caches/) (*src/mem/cache/*).

In gem5 the number of cache ways is determined automatically from the cache size and the associativity. Check the files in *src/mem/cache/tags/indexing_policies/* for the relevant code (specifically, the constructor of *base.cc*).

There are two ways you could tackle this implementation:

1 - Create a new class that inherits from **BaseTags** (e.g., **HybCacheTags**). This class will contain the decision of whether it should work in secure mode or not, and how to do so (i.e., when to call which indexing and replacement policy). Depending on whatever else is proposed in the paper, you may also need to derive from **Cache** to create a **HybCache**.

- The new tags need one [indexing policy](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/memory_system/indexing_policies/) per operation mode. One is the conventional (**SetAssociative**), and the other is derived from **SetAssociative**, where the parameter *assoc* makes the *numSets* become 1 (to make it fully associative). The derived one will also have to override at least one function, *getPossibleEntries()*, to only allow selecting the ways that you want. You can check *skewed_assoc.cc* for an example of a more complex location selection.
- The new tags need one [replacement policy](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/memory_system/replacement_policies/) per operation mode. You will likely just use the ones in the *replacement_policies* folder.

2 - You could create a **HybCache** based on the **Cache** class that has two tags, one conventional (i.e., **BaseSetAssoc**), and the other based on the **FALRU** class (rewritten to work as a, e.g., **FARandom**).

I believe the first option is easier and less hardcoded. **FALRU** has not been split into an indexing policy and replacement policy, so if you need to change one of these, you will have to reimplement it.

While implementing you may encounter coherence faults. If it happens it is much likely a problem in the indexing logic, and I wouldn't look into trying to find issues in the coherence model.